# Makefile called from IDE for Debug/Release

Tags: c++, linux, parameters, makefile

I have Makefile project under IDE and two build versions: Debug and Release. IDE sends make command: "make -f Makefile Debug" or "make -f Makefile Release".
I cannot find way how to change ccflags-y by parameter "Debug" or "Release". What is proper way ? My simplified Makefile sees like this:

```
ccflags-y += -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DDEFINE1 -DDEFINE2

mkfile_dir := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

Debug: ccflags-y += -DDEBUG -g3 -O0  # NOT FUNCTIONAL !
Release: ccflags-y += -DNDEBUG -O2   # NOT FUNCTIONAL !
Debug: all
Release: all
cleanDebug: clean
cleanRelease: clean

obj-m := modulesrc.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(mkfile_dir) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(mkfile_dir) clean
```

---

Answer (score 0):

First I tried to write ifeq condition which tests $(MAKECMDGOALS), but it was not functional, because this Makefile calls other Makefiles when building module and in sub-Makefiles is other target than Debug/Release. I found other solution but still I am not sure if is it correct way. I changed IDE cmdline starting make: "make -f Makefile mytarget=Debug" or "make -f Makefile mytarget=Release" then I add condition into Makefile:

```
ccflags-y += -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DDEFINE1 -DDEFINE2

mkfile_dir := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

ifeq ($(mytarget),Debug)
ccflags-y += -DDEBUG -O0
endif

ifeq ($(mytarget),Release)
ccflags-y += -DNDEBUG -O2
endif

cleanDebug: clean
cleanRelease: clean

obj-m := modulesrc.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(mkfile_dir) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(mkfile_dir) clean
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the other makefile, but give this a try:

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(mkfile_dir) modules ccflags-y=$(ccflagS-Y)

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(mkfile_dir) clean ccflags-y=$(ccflagS-Y)
```

Comment: Other makefile is part of kernel sources. Even I have solved it I tried it, it is not functional. In source compilation compiler does not know required defines.